# File upload with mysql don't works

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i wrote a simple upload system but the upload system doesn't works. i hope you can help me!

my php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['taskAdd'])) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['taskFile1']['tmp_name'], '../files/' . $_FILES['taskFile1']['name']);
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks (taskFile1) VALUES (:taskFile1)");
    $stmt->execute();
            header("Location: /index/");
}
```

the error message:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../files/login.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions\taskAdd.php on line 13

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpA9F3.tmp' to '../files/login.html' in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions\taskAdd.php on line 13

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':taskFile1)' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions\taskAdd.php:15 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\functions\taskAdd.php(15): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\tasks\add\index.php(7): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\functions\taskAdd.php on line 4
```

HTML FORM:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post' name='taskAdd'>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="taskFile1">Hochladen1:</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="taskFile1" id="taskFile1">
                                            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to [**READ THE MANUAL**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: What is the datatype of  taskFile1 field in tasks table? Are you trying to store the file info(name, path etc) or the complete file as binary inside database?

Comment: the datatype of taskFile1 is varchar and i will save only the name in database and the file in the folder "file".

Comment: you're supposed to bind after prepare before `execute()`

Comment: post your full HTML form

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi i edit my post, now you can see my form.

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing `'../files/' . $_FILES['taskFile1']['name']` as the second parameter to move_uploaded_file, you need to pass:

`dirname(__FILE__) . '/files/' . $_FILES['taskFile1']['name']`

or better,

`dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'files' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_FILES['taskFile1']['name']`

Also, you have to make sure permissions of the '../files/' directory are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1)https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

2)$name=$_FILES[$v1]['name'];

```
    $tmpname=$_FILES["taskFile1"]['tmp_name'];//filetoupload is a name attribute of file input tag.

    $target_dir = "uploads/"; //folder name where your files will be stored. create this folder inside "file_upload_api" folder
    $target_file = $target_dir.$name ;
    move_uploaded_file($tmpname,$target_file)
```

//and insert the name of file into databse for further operations

//add button in html to perform uploading

Answer (score 0):

1. Your insert statement is not correct.
2. You didn't provide the insert parameter. i.e. binding

it should be:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks (taskFile1) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_FILES['taskFile1']['name']);
$stmt->execute();
```